How to get single colorbar with shared x- and y-axis for seaborn heatmaps in subplot?
I want to plot multiple confusion matrices in a single plot with a single colorbar and with a shared x- and y-axis. Here is my code I have tried so far
#Calculate the onfusion matrices
predicted_mod1 = df_binary["Model1"]
actual_class = df_binary["Observed"]

out_df_mod1 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([predicted_mod1, actual_class]).T,columns=['predicted_class','actual_class'])
CF_mod1 = pd.crosstab(out_df_mod1['actual_class'], out_df_mod1['predicted_class'], rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'])

predicted_mod2 = df_binary["Model2"]

out_df_mod2 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([predicted_mod2, actual_class]).T,columns=['predicted_class','actual_class'])
CF_mod2 = pd.crosstab(out_df_mod2['actual_class'], out_df_mod2['predicted_class'], rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'])

predicted_mod4 = df_binary["Model4"]

out_df_mod4 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([predicted_mod4, actual_class]).T,columns=['predicted_class','actual_class'])
CF_mod4 = pd.crosstab(out_df_mod4['actual_class'], out_df_mod4['predicted_class'], rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'])

predicted_mod5 = df_binary["Model5"]

out_df_mod5 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([predicted_mod5, actual_class]).T,columns=['predicted_class','actual_class'])
CF_mod5 = pd.crosstab(out_df_mod5['actual_class'], out_df_mod5['predicted_class'], rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'])

predicted_mod6 = df_binary["Model6"]

out_df_mod6 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([predicted_mod6, actual_class]).T,columns=['predicted_class','actual_class'])
CF_mod6 = pd.crosstab(out_df_mod6['actual_class'], out_df_mod6['predicted_class'], rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'])

Now I have plotted these matrices using the following code
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3), dpi=300)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.8, wspace=0.6)

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 1)
sns.heatmap(CF_mod1, cmap='Blues', annot=True, fmt='d')

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 2)
sns.heatmap(CF_mod2, cmap='Blues', annot=True, fmt='d')

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 3)
sns.heatmap(CF_mod3, cmap='Blues', annot=True, fmt='d')

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 4)
sns.heatmap(CF_mod4, cmap='Blues', annot=True, fmt='d')

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 5)
sns.heatmap(CF_mod5, cmap='Blues', annot=True, fmt='d')

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 6)
sns.heatmap(CF_mod6, cmap='Blues', annot=True, fmt='d')

plt.show()


My expected output is something like the following

Now how can I have only one single colorbar with a shared x- and y-axis?
Data
Model1,Model2,Model3,Model4,Model5,Model6,Observed
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
No,No,No,No,No,No,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,No,Yes,No,Yes,Yes
No,Yes,No,No,No,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,No,No,No,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,No,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,No,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,Yes
Yes,No,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,Yes,No,No,No,Yes,No
No,Yes,No,No,No,Yes,No
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,Yes,No,Yes,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No
No,No,No,No,No,No,No


Does this answer your question? One colorbar for seaborn heatmaps in subplot

@ParmanM.Alizadeh I have seen that post. That is a simple heatmap plot. Here first I am calculating confusion matrices then I am trying to plot those matrices.

@UseR10085 But they are heatmaps, so it's the same exact thing.

@jared Please see if you can answer my question using my dataset with the help of that answer.

Following the logic from this answer, you can then loop through the subplots (with sharex=True and sharey=True to remove the ticks from plots not on the edges), plot the data, and remove the ylabel if it's not in the first column and/or xlabel if it's not in the last row. To ensure the right color scale, a global vmin and vmax is computed before the loop.
nrows = 2
ncols = 3
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex=True, sharey=True)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.91, 0.3, 0.03, 0.4])

data = [CF_mod1, CF_mod2, CF_mod3, CF_mod4, CF_mod5, CF_mod6]

# get global min and max to enforce the same colorscale in all plots
vmin = min([d.min().min() for d in data])
vmax = max([d.max().max() for d in data])

for i, (ax, d) in enumerate(zip(axes.flat, data)):
    p = sns.heatmap(d, ax=ax, annot=True,
                    vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax,
                    cmap="Blues", cbar=(i==0), cbar_ax=None if i else cbar_ax)
    # remove ylabel if not in the first column
    if i%ncols:
        ax.set_ylabel("")
    # remove xlabel if not in the last row
    if i//ncols + 1 != nrows:
        ax.set_xlabel("")
fig.show()

Result:

For the axes labels, you can also use suplabels and remove the individual axes labels.
for i, (ax, d) in enumerate(zip(axes.flat, data)):
    p = sns.heatmap(d, ax=ax, annot=True,
                    vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax,
                    cmap="Blues", cbar=False)
    ax.set_xlabel("")
    ax.set_ylabel("")
fig.supxlabel("Predicted")
fig.supylabel("Actual")

Result:


Edit: To put a title above each plot simply add ax.set_title to the loop.
for i, (ax, d) in enumerate(zip(axes.flat, data)):
    p = sns.heatmap(d, ax=ax, annot=True,
                    vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax,
                    cmap="Blues", cbar=(i==0), cbar_ax=None if i else cbar_ax)
    ax.set_xlabel("")
    ax.set_ylabel("")
    ax.set_title(f"Model {i+1}")

Result:


Edit: To automate the titles, use the dataframe columns.

for i, (ax, d, title) in enumerate(zip(axes.flat, data, df_binary.columns)):
    ...
    ax.set_title(title)


The second part is not returning any plot. It returns me Text(0.02, 0.5, 'Actual'). How can I have the heatmap titles like Model 1, Model 2, Model 3 like that.

You must be using a Jupyter notebook. Make sure the figure is created in the same cell as the rest of the code. And I'm not sure what you're asking about for titles. You want there to be a title above each plot?

Yes title above the plot. I am using Jupyter notebook.

Then just add ax.set_title into the loop.

I added the titles code and also simplified the colorbar stuff to be similar to the linked answer.

The titles are fixed in the code. Can it pick up from the data?

@UseR10085 See the updated code at the end. (Warning: I'm no longer at my computer and wrote it on my phone, so it's untested.)
